# Business Intelligence Center

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, business-intelligence

I don't see a site template to Business Intelligence Center.  How could to turn on this template ?

I don't see any icon of Busines Intelligence. Is my version to low ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I found a resolution for my problem:

http://bi-architects.blogspot.com/2011/12/sharepoint-2010-business-intelligence.html

If You don't see Business Inteligence Center You should do this steps, and activate Features:

1. Site Settings | Site Actions | Site Collection Administration | Site
   Collection Features | Activate SharePoint Server Publishing
   Infrastructure
2. Site Settings | Site Actions | Site Collection
   Administration | Site Collection Features | Activate
   PerformancePoint Services Site collection features
3. Site Settings |
   Site Actions | Site Collection Administration | Site Collection
   Features | Activate PerformancePoint Services Site Features

And after refresh cache, the template will shown.

Comment: Please add more details to this answer, if the link breaks your answer will be of no help to future readers

Comment: Updated answer :)